# Ubuntu 22.04 screen "quick freezes" when moving the mouse to the bottom of the screen

Tags: 22.04, mouse, display-resolution, screen, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Qfter last update these fast freezes started. It happens every time I move the mouse to bottom of the screen. It doesn't matter if I use a bluetooth mouse or the mouse pad.

I've noticed that when I low the resolution that problem stops. It only happens when I'm using 2560x1600 (16:10) resolution, but it not a hardware issue because, as I said, this wasn't happening until the last update.

Specs:

[image]

Comment: My setup is similar to yours (same CPU w/ integrated graphics), and I am running into this exact issue... you're not alone.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the Intel driver. I have a similar setup and issue and when I force it to use the NVidia driver all the time, the problem goes away. If you have a non-Intel graphics card, try and force it to use that. Otherwise, I guess we just wait for an update or downgrade drivers/kernels.